# ActionMailer: Simultaneously sending an email to Admin & Email to Client - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am unsure how to resolve this - any help would be much appreciated.

when a client completes a contact form, i would like to know how to use ActionMailer to send an email to the admin (akunorbea@gmail.com) and to the client (client@gmail.com).

my terminal shows that the emails are being sent to the admin (akunorbea@gmail.com) & client (client@gmail.com)
[image]

- when i check my admin(akunorbea@gmail.com) i see the email.
- but when i check the client(client@gmail.com) account i do not see an email.
- Could one advise me how to correct this so i see both emails in both account

schema

```
  create_table "contacts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "category_department_id"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "category_enquiry_id"
    t.string   "tel"
  end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        MailerContact.contact_us(@contact).deliver
        MailerContact.contact_us_confirmation(@contact).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to message_sent_path, :notice => 'message sent' }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @contact, :status => :created, :location => [@contact] }
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

mailer_contact.rb

```
class MailerContact < ActionMailer::Base

  def contact_us(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail( to: "akunorbea@gmail.com", 
          subject: "Client Enquiries", 
          from: "#{contact.firstname} <#{contact.email}>")
  end

  def contact_us_confirmation(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail( to: "#{contact.firstname} <#{contact.email}>", 
          subject: "Thank you for your Enquiries", 
          from: "<no-reply@africanjober.com>")
  end
end
```

html.erb files

```
contact_us.html.erb
This email goes to the admin (akunorbea@gmail.com)
"displays Client enquiries" 

contact_us_confirmation.html.erb
This email goes to the client (client@gmail.com)
"Thank you for your enquiries"
```

Answer (score 0):

action mailer only sends one email at a time. Not built to send 2 emails simultaneously for the same action in the same controller